gtsummary::tbl_summary error when calculating sd for continuous variables
When I try to run:
mtcars %>%
  select(vs, mpg, disp) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = vs,
    type = list(c(mpg, disp) ~ "continuous"),
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})")
  ) 

I get:
✖ There was an error calculating the summary statistics for "mpg". Is this variable's class supported by `mean` and `sd`?
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `df_stats = pmap(...)`.
Caused by error in `pmap()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `abort()`:
! `message` must be a character vector, not a <rlang_error> object.
Backtrace:
  1. mtcars %>% select(vs, mpg, disp) %>% ...
 23. gtsummary:::safe_summarise_at(., variable = variable, fns = fns)
 24. base::tryCatch(...)
 25. base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 26. base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 27. value[[3L]](cond)
 28. rlang::abort(message = e)


I tried to update R (4.4.0), RStudio (2024.04.0+735) and related packages (gtsummary 1.7.2, tidyverse 2.0.0, rlang 1.1.3)
When I drop {mean} the error repeat, but when I remove {sd} then the code runs without an error
It happens to both continuous variables, and both are classified as dbl
This bit of code worked in the past
The problem occurs on a specific project, but not on a fresh new one


Session info:
R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.3.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.12.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: Asia/Jerusalem
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] EnvStats_2.8.1         gt_0.10.1              marginaleffects_0.20.1 MatchIt_4.5.5         
 [5] labelled_2.13.0        scales_1.3.0           ggsci_3.0.3            flextable_0.9.6       
 [9] gtsummary_1.7.2        haven_2.5.4            readxl_1.4.3           lubridate_1.9.3       
[13] forcats_1.0.0          stringr_1.5.1          dplyr_1.1.4            purrr_1.0.2           
[17] readr_2.1.5            tidyr_1.3.1            tibble_3.2.1           ggplot2_3.5.1         
[21] tidyverse_2.0.0        pacman_0.5.1          

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.2.1        farver_2.1.1            fastmap_1.1.1           fontquiver_0.2.1       
 [5] promises_1.3.0          broom.helpers_1.15.0    digest_0.6.35           timechange_0.3.0       
 [9] mime_0.12               lifecycle_1.0.4         gfonts_0.2.0            magrittr_2.0.3         
[13] compiler_4.4.0          rlang_1.1.3             tools_4.4.0             utf8_1.2.4             
[17] yaml_2.3.8              data.table_1.15.4       knitr_1.46              labeling_0.4.3         
[21] askpass_1.2.0           curl_5.2.1              xml2_1.3.6              httpcode_0.3.0         
[25] withr_3.0.0             grid_4.4.0              fansi_1.0.6             gdtools_0.3.7          
[29] xtable_1.8-4            colorspace_2.1-0        crul_1.4.2              insight_0.19.10        
[33] cli_3.6.2               rmarkdown_2.26          crayon_1.5.2            ragg_1.3.1             
[37] generics_0.1.3          rstudioapi_0.16.0       tzdb_0.4.0              cellranger_1.1.0       
[41] vctrs_0.6.5             sandwich_3.1-0          jsonlite_1.8.8          fontBitstreamVera_0.1.1
[45] hms_1.1.3               systemfonts_1.0.6       glue_1.7.0              stringi_1.8.4          
[49] gtable_0.3.5            later_1.3.2             munsell_0.5.1           pillar_1.9.0           
[53] htmltools_0.5.8.1       openssl_2.1.2           R6_2.5.1                textshaping_0.3.7      
[57] evaluate_0.23           shiny_1.8.1.1           lattice_0.22-6          backports_1.4.1        
[61] fontLiberation_0.1.0    httpuv_1.6.15           Rcpp_1.0.12             zip_2.3.1              
[65] uuid_1.2-0              checkmate_2.3.1         officer_0.6.6           xfun_0.43              
[69] zoo_1.8-12              pkgconfig_2.0.3 


how about a toy/data sample for the sake of reproducibility?

I changed the df to mtcars for reproducibility @AdrianoMello

Thanks for updating your example to be reproducible.
The below code shows that I can run your example without error. Moreover, this is pretty basic functionality for tbl_summary(). Before I submit it to CRAN, I run a comprehensive test suite on 6 versions of R, tests on Windows, MacOS, and Linux. Then after it goes to CRAN, they run the test suite on about 12 more systems. All these tests are passing.
Unfortunately, that doesn't help much with your exact scenario. Typically in this situation, I would recommend you re-install gtsummary (and all dependencies).
When you updated your R version, did you perform a fresh install of all R packages and did not copy them from your previous installation? If not a fresh install, please force a new installation from CRAN.
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.2'

mtcars %>%
  select(vs, mpg, disp) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = vs,
    type = list(c(mpg, disp) ~ "continuous"),
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})")
  ) |> 
  as_kable() # convert to kable so table will display on SO




Characteristic
0, N = 18
1, N = 14




mpg
16.6 (3.9)
24.6 (5.4)


disp
307 (107)
132 (57)



Created on 2024-05-11 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you, Daniel; I got to the same conclusion and already re-installed everything freshly with dependencies - still the same. It is even weirder than I thought - the problem is with a specific project, but it works with a fresh project.

Found it! It wasn't the project itself but the data in the R environment. When I cleared the environment, everything worked. I guess it was related to one of the variable's names that collided with a function.
